# LIKE query in Entity Framework with SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, ef-code-first

I'm having the following problem with a EF CodeFirst query using SQL Server Compact as the backend.

The LINQ expression is:

```
var results = (from c in x.Countries where c.Name.StartsWith(term) select c);
```

According to what I've found, the output should use a LIKE operator in the WHERE clause, but instead the SQL being run is:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [Countries] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (CHARINDEX(@p__linq__0, [Extent1].[Name])) = 1
```

What is going on?

**EDIT:** I also tried using Contains(term), the generated SQL is different, but it doesn't use LIKE either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CHARINDEX is equivalent, with slightly better performance.

Why do you need a LIKE?

**Update**: there's a better way to do what you need.

Instead of making the queries more complex, make the column **accent-insensitive**.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    Name nvarchar(50) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI,
    ...
```

(A slightly better way is making the whole DB accent-insensitive by default)

This way, you (or EF) can write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Countries
WHERE CHARINDEX('Mex', Name) = 1
/*or Name LIKE 'Mex%'*/
```

And it will find **Mexico**, **México**, etc. It's easier to deal with and more user friendly (think of Google: it doesn't force you to use special syntax to find accented/non-accented variants)

Comment: I'm working with country names in spanish. So for example if I'm looking for México (notice the mark above the 'e') I want to find it even if the user inputs Mexico (without the mark). With LIKE I would do a query similar to this: WHERE [Name] LIKE N'M[eé]x%'. If to the above code I provide StartsWith("M[eé]x") the code returns an empty list.

Comment: The app I'm making is a fairly simple thing so I'm letting EF create the DB. Is there a way to make the DB EF creates Accent-Insensitive?

Comment: @Kiranu: after creating it, you can run `ALTER DATABASE [name_of_the_db] COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI`